# How to create a Javascript pie chart with list data?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, pie-chart

So my data is currently in the format of

```
[
    {
        "B": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 1
    }
]
```

To which I want to create a pie chart with. However the sample pie chart I have used online expects data like this.

```
        [
            {y: 1, label: "User Group A"},
            {y: 1, label: "User Group B"},
        ]
```

This is the pie chart code I found online

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Did user group view page on ebay?"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        startAngle: 240,
        yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"",
        indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
        dataPoints: [
            {y: 1, label: "User Group A"},
            {y: 1, label: "User Group B"},
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();
```

How would I best convert my data to {y: data, label: "data"}?

or would I be best using a different Javascript pie chart which supports the format of my data better?

Comment: in your data, the keys should be same right?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
[
    {
        "B": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 1
    }
].map(data => {
    let key  = Object.keys(data)[0]
    return {y : data[key], label: key}
})
```